# Get option's value via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have select list:

```
<select id="category_list" name="aName">
<option value="#menu_1463">News 1</option>
<option value="#menu_1738">News 2</option>
<option value="#menu_1526">News 3</option>
</select>
```

And every value has a `li` in my structure:

```
<ul class="site_list">
    <li id="menu_1463">

        <h3>News 1</h3>

        <div class="site_list_box">

            <div class="img"><img src="image.jpg" alt=""></div>
            .....

        </li>

</ul>
```

Now, when I click the anything `option`, slide down to `li`. However I want, all `li` is `display:none` and when click `option`, `display:block` by fade effect.

How can I do it?

Thanks.

Comment: You forgot to post the JavaScript/jQuery you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## [See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v2ZUB/)

This should give you a crude, but reasonably starting point.

HTML

```
<select>
    <option value='item1'>Item 1</option>
    <option value='item2'>Item 2</option>
    <option value='item3'>Item 3</option>    
</select>


<ul>
    <li id='item1'>Item 1 Content</li>
    <li id='item2'>Item 2 Content</li>
    <li id='item3'>Item 3 Content</li>    
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul{
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
ul li{
    display:none;
}
```

jQuery

```
$('select').on('change', function(){
    $('li').hide();
    $('#'+$(this).val()).fadeIn();
})
```

You can also change it to the below if you need to scroll to the item on the page:

```
$('select').on('change', function(){
    $('li').hide();
    $('#'+$(this).val()).fadeIn();
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $('#'+$(this).val()).offset().top},'slow');
})
```

Comment: You should use `this.value` instead of `$(this).val()` as it's faster.